# update millions of rows in oracle

Tags: optimization, plsql

I am trying to update 5 million rows. Below query runs in 5-6 minutes. But I want to have periodic commit in between 500000 records. How do i do that?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

```
DECLARE
   a   NUMBER;
   BEGIN
   UPDATE table1
    SET (name) =
         (SELECT name
            FROM table1
           WHERE     a1= 24672

   WHERE ROWNUM <= 6500000;

   a := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (a || ' Rows Updated');
END;
/
```

Comment: its just a name change so even if it throws an error, after 5 millions that would be okay with me.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have tagged this 'optimization' I assume you care about performance.  Whilst you could rewrite your SQL in PL/SQL, use a loop and commit every n iterations, this is going to slow you down.

The fastest way to update millions of rows is often in fact not to update at all.  Instead you create a new table (CREATE TABLE ... AS ... SELECT ), drop your old table and then rename your new table.  It reduces the amount of redo and undo and greatly speeds up performance.

See [How to update millions of rows](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:6407993912330)

If performance is good enough then possibly you no longer care about partial commits?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something similar to this.

```
DECLARE
   a   NUMBER;
   commitCt NUMBER;
   rowCt NUMBER;

   BEGIN
      LOOP
         commitCt := 0;
         rowCt := 0;
         SAVEPOINT svePoint;

     WHILE rowCt/500000 <= 1
     LOOP
       BEGIN
           rowCt := rowCt + 1;



           commitCt := commitCt + 1;

       EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
           ROLLBACK to svePoint;
       END;

      END LOOP;

     COMMIT;

     IF commitCt = 0 THEN
        EXIT;
     END IF;

      END LOOP;
END;
/
```